# what is the particle size effect in chaos?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I am studying dynamical system. As far as I know, chaotic behavior can be developed for one particle moving in a certain potential in 3D, and for this case, the position of the particle will be the mathematical point.

How about the cases of two or many body system? If there are chaotic behavior, I guess the particle volume has to be considered in the collision. Maybe not-infinitesimal particle volume regularize the dynamical system so that the dynamics goes nicely, or the size effect has nothing to do with chaos. I have no idea, but I couldn't find any in the literature.

Is there any accounts on this aspect? Thank you.